# SSIS Record the number of times a package has been executed

Tags: logging, ssis, count, package, execution

This sounds very simple to do but I have only limited experience of using SSIS.

Basically what I want to do is have a series of tasks within a SSIS package, the first step of the package is to check that the previous run was completed successfully and check the Run Number.

Secondly if this was successful then is to get the previous Run Number and increment by 1 and create a new Started Run record with this new number. Then call the other tasks within the package one at a time. Again once these have all been successfully run create a Completed Successfully record.

I have no idea where to start with this, having never touched this type of error handling and check before. What I need to know is how I go about recording the Run Number, I cannot see anywhere is SSIS that allows me to record a count of the successfully executed package.

I have a log table that logs insert, update and delete counts.

For example if I had a package with 10 modules I need to log the insert, update and delete counts along with their durations and create a log entry for each module as its own record. However I need to log against these the Run Number of the entire package. So the log table will have e.g. Run Number 1 against 10 tasks, Run Number 2 against another 10 tasks etc.

[image]

This is an image of the table I am logging to, I hope I have explained this well enough for anyone to understand. As you can see this was after one package execution, I would expect the RunNumber here to be 1, then if I executed the package again I would need the next 3 records to have a RunNumber of 2 and so on.

Comment: Is there some reason this isn't as simple as using the Execute SQL task to update your log table?   Any additional information you need about runs can be kept in another table which you would create for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I agree I would create a new table with the run number and package number. The package number would be a foreign key to your package table. The new table would be something like PackageRunCount. Inside the SSIS package and oledb command is run to increment the runnumber by one depending on the package number e.g. update packagecount set runnumber = (select max runnumber from PackageRunCount) + 1. Then you can join on this table to see the details of the package and how many times it has been run.